# Python Tkinter Inventory sum

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am new to python and saw a source code regarding some inventory app made with tkinter and I got the hang of it modifying and trying to understand the code but there's something I cant seem to do, calculating the total price of the product(quantity * price). When i multiply the PRODUCT_QTY and PRODUCT_PRICE it returns 0 so I dont know how to asign the value to the tkinter variables IntVar().Here is the code of the viewform of the created products:

```
def ViewForm():
global tree
TopViewForm = Frame(viewform, width=600, bd=1, relief=SOLID)
TopViewForm.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
LeftViewForm = Frame(viewform, width=600)
LeftViewForm.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
MidViewForm = Frame(viewform, width=600)
MidViewForm.pack(side=RIGHT)
lbl_text = Label(TopViewForm, text="View Products", font=('arial', 18), width=600)
lbl_text.pack(fill=X)
lbl_txtsearch = Label(LeftViewForm, text="Search", font=('arial', 15))
lbl_txtsearch.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
search = Entry(LeftViewForm, textvariable=SEARCH, font=('arial', 15), width=10)
search.pack(side=TOP,  padx=10, fill=X)
btn_search = Button(LeftViewForm, text="Search", command=Search)
btn_search.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10, fill=X)
btn_reset = Button(LeftViewForm, text="Reset", command=Reset)
btn_reset.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10, fill=X)
btn_delete = Button(LeftViewForm, text="Delete", command=Delete)
btn_delete.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10, fill=X)
scrollbarx = Scrollbar(MidViewForm, orient=HORIZONTAL)
scrollbary = Scrollbar(MidViewForm, orient=VERTICAL)
tree = ttk.Treeview(MidViewForm, columns=("ProductID", "Product Name", "Product Qty", "Product Price"), selectmode="extended", height=100, yscrollcommand=scrollbary.set, xscrollcommand=scrollbarx.set)
scrollbary.config(command=tree.yview)
scrollbary.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
scrollbarx.config(command=tree.xview)
scrollbarx.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
tree.heading('ProductID', text="ProductID",anchor=W)
tree.heading('Product Name', text="Product Name",anchor=W)
tree.heading('Product Qty', text="Product Qty",anchor=W)
tree.heading('Product Price', text="Product Price",anchor=W)
tree.column('#0', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=0)
tree.column('#1', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=0)
tree.column('#2', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=200)
tree.column('#3', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=120)
tree.column('#4', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=120)
tree.pack()
DisplayData()
```

Comment: P.S the variables are declared like this  then retrieved from a database :USERNAME = StringVar()
PASSWORD = StringVar()
PRODUCT_NAME = StringVar()
PRODUCT_PRICE = IntVar()
PRODUCT_QTY = IntVar()
SEARCH = StringVar(

Comment: Did you try casting them to numerical types in case they were in a possible 'string' state ?

Comment: _"I dont know how to asign the value to the tkinter variables IntVar()"_ - Have you read documentation on `IntVar`? That will tell you how to set the values.

Comment: Yes i typecasted them and used the .get() attribute but the problem is with getting the values from them since when i multiply them it returns 0, even if the qty and price are numbers(1,2) or something.I want to get the values form the database and display the total without having to do calculations every time(queries)

Comment: *"When i multiply the PRODUCT_QTY and PRODUCT_PRICE it returns 0"*: Unfortunatly your code didn't show that. Your **whole** code in the Question is not usefull for what you are asking. [Edit] your Question and replace it with the relevant part.

Comment: Its just a calculation like this total = int(PRODUCT_QTY.get()) * int(PRODUCT_PRICE.get())

Comment: *"Its just a calculation like this"*: **Sure**, but **where** in your codeflow did you input the date, **how** did you call this *calculation*. **What** gives the output of e.g. `print(PRODUCT_QTY.get()` and so on. **PLEASE** [Edit] your Question and show all this.